# Is there any way to set RAM location (in java) to a variable so that we can retrieve value?

Tags: java, security, ram

If I have not assumed or learned anything wrong then all variables that we assign, takes a certain place of the RAM.
For example while working with Java array when we try to print an array it prints a "location".

> String [] a = new String [2]
>
> System.out.println(a)
>
> [Ljava.lang.String;@be6280

Now is there any way to set that location?

I think it is possible using C++, is it? If any language offers this thing then I should be capable to scan my RAM for that variable or array location at least exhaustively. Can't I? Have anyone tried doing it?

Comment: What it displays is not a RAM location. It's the hashCode of the array. And Java can't access any location in RAM. What exactly would you like to do?

Comment: Thanks a lot.
It may sound crazy but I want to scan the whole RAM to retrieve a variable value. Is it some what possible?

Explain with code:

>int [] fake;

>for(int RamLocation : possibleLocations){
>fake.setLocation(RamLocation);

>if(fake != null){
>print fake;
>}
>}

Comment: I still don't understand, because RAM doesn't contain variables, but bytes, and because the code you give doesn't make any sense. What do you REALLY want to do. Did you wake up this morning thinking: I'll try to scan the ram of my computer? Or do you want to create a program that does something concrete? If the latter: what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Unsafe class as shown [here](http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/direct-memory-access-in-java/).  This is specific to the HotSpot JVM, but it's probably a start.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is in Java not possible. For developpers of debugging tools, and special other tools there is a backdoor for direct memory access, but this is not that what you and 99.995% of other people want.

Comment: well its possible as shown by @AndresOlarte, but best avoided in 99% of situations

Answer (score 0):

Memory in Java (RAM) is controlled by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) and there is no way, unlike other programming environments, to handle memory allocation manually in the Java heap. You can allocate memory outside Java using JNI or NIO.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the location is very unsafe as the GC can be performed at any time and a corrupt memory structure will crash the JVM.

You can get the location of a object, but you don't need this.  You can use Reflections to get any field of an object, but you can use Unsafe to extract or set a field.